# How do I sort query results by keyword occurrence in column? (SQL Server Full-Text)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

How do I sort the query results by keyword occurrence in column? I'm using SQL Server 2008 with Full-text indexing.

Answer (score 1):

select columnname, count(columnname)  as cnt from tablename group by columnname order by count(columnname) desc

Answer (score 0):

select * from tablename order by columnname

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I meant the keyword occurrence, for example, if this keyword is "car", record A contains 3 occurrence and record B has 5, then record B should rank higher.